# sendEmail method in dynamically created button?

Tags: android, email, button, android-intent, dynamic

I dynamically created buttons and I want to send an email by clicking on these buttons, but something goes wrong. Nothing happens. :( Please help me, I am beginner.

AdapterListingOrders:

```
public class AdapterListingOrders extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnAccRejOrders;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adapter_listing_orders);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    btnAccRejOrders = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order_acc_rej);

    btnAccRejOrders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Send email", "");
            String[] TO = {""};
            String[] CC = {""};
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");
        }
    });
}
}
```

But onClick does not work. When I press the btnAccRejOrders, LogCat display:

```
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

Comment: r u trying in emulator or real device

Comment: if u created buttons dynamically then how can you find it by its view's id from xml ? ?

Comment: @Naveen in real device, Samsung J7, logcat displays the same 
ViewPostImeInoutStage processPointer 0 and 1.

Comment: @AalapPatel    I created button in adapter_listing_order.xml and then in activity I have private class ListingOrdersAdapter extends BaseAdapter, so buttons are created as many as I have data in Firebase. 

I followed this tutorial: http://coderzpassion.com/saving-retrieving-data-firebase-android-part-one/

Answer (score 0):

```
btnAccRejOrders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Send email", "");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
            try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The same problem still here :(